# LUIS Intent Score

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am trying to built a sample using LUIS intents to call my API, but the intent score for "CharacterSearch" is something I am not able to understand.
Could anyone please look into below response and advise how the intent score is more than 1 or I am missing something here, intent score for "SearchSigil" is perfect.
My main concern is this a normal score ?
If needed I can post my intents and entities.

```
{
  "query": "Which sigil displays three headed dragon",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "SearchSigil",
    "score": 0.9916578
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "SearchSigil",
      "score": 0.9916578
    },
    {
      "intent": "SearchHouses",
      "score": 0.0689159855
    },
    {
      "intent": "None",
      "score": 0.0170753412
    },
    {
      "intent": "Help",
      "score": 0.005770977
    },
    {
      "intent": "Cancel",
      "score": 0.00406856835
    },
    {
      "intent": "Greeting",
      "score": 0.00150005356
    },
    {
      "intent": "CharacterSearch",
      "score": 3.12414272E-08
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "three headed dragon",
      "type": "Sigil",
      "startIndex": 21,
      "endIndex": 39,
      "resolution": {
        "values": [
          "three headed dragon"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your score is not higher than 1.
The score 3.12414272E-08 equals 0.000000031241427

See: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3.12414272E-08

Comment: Wow should have looked more properly ! Thanks !